# Is it possible to catch user response timestamp for each response in google forms?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am performing a survey using **Google forms** and storing responses in **Google spreadsheet**.

Though I am receiving the *timestamp* of update/submission in my response spreadsheet, but I also wanted to store response/update *timestamp* of each response.

So can any one guide or suggest me how to capture the *timestamp* of each response in google forms.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: From each response, I mean response by user to each question in survey form.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to do that using native google forms hosted on google. in fact you cant run any javascript while the user fills the form so there is no way to pass that extra information when the form is hosted by google.

it is possible (but undocumented and not supported officially) to take the generated clientside form code and host it yourself, then you can add clientside javascript and collect the extra info. ive seen one site that shows you how to do it.